# I need a root password to access my drives, how to install 13.04?

Tags: installation, 11.10, password, root

My PC crashed a week ago and by using Multi Bios I found I could "Try Or Install Ubuntu". I have never used this before and every time I try to access my drives it says I need a root password or I need to authenticate. I have Googled these things but the answers seem aimed at experts, not noobs. I appear to be running 11.10 signed in as a "guest" but when I download 13.04, I have no idea how to install it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded `ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso`? Good. I'll asume you downloaded it on another computer running Windows, if not, comment. Now, do the following:

1. Grab an empty DVD or an USB stick and put it in the computer you downloaded it on.
2. If you use a DVD, [follow the instructions here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/burn-a-cd-or-dvd-from-an-iso-file). If you use an USB, backup the files that are on it, format it (as FAT32), [download UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and run it, click the round button next to the word ISO, click the `...` button, choose the downloaded ISO, make sure the selected drive letter is the same as the one of the USB and then press OK. After it's done press Exit.
3. Boot from the DVD or USB from the crashed computer.

You can now try out Ubuntu or install it. Ubuntu 13.04 should not ask for root passwords when accessing drives.

Ubuntu is a great operating system, I don't think you will be dissapointed.
Good luck!